# Clojure Hystrix exceptions because of too many http requests

Tags: http, clojure, clojurescript, hystrix

I need to build a system that needs to make a a ton of external http requests and I have to use Netflix's Hystrix to create fallbacks and re-route exceptions. Right now, I've got a very simple setup:

```
(hystrix/defcommand fetch-request
    {:hystrix/group-key "c0"
     :hystrix/command-key "URLFetch"
     :hystrix/fallback-fn (fn [url]
                                                    {:status 419
                                                     :headers {}
                                                     :body "failed"})}
    [url]
    @(http/get url))


(defn test3 []
    (let [n 4000
        m (range 0 n)
        p (partition 300 m)]
        (doseq [t p]
            (thread
                (doseq [x t]
                    (let [res (fetch-request "http://localhost:3000/comments")]
                        (match (:status res)
                            200 (prn x)
                            :else (prn nil)))
                    )))
        ))
```

When I execute `test3`, I keep getting `nil`. If I decrease the value of `n`, I get a status of `200` (which is what I need). Furthermore, if I just use `http/get` directly on `test3` function instead of `fetch-request` command, it works  without any problem (even when the value of n is above 7000).

Note: The reason I'm using partitions+threads is to parallelize the http requests. If you know a better way to execute large volume of http requests in clojure as fast as possible, that would be really awesome.

Update:

I played w/ a variety of configurations. Most of them didn't yield a different outcome. Most of the reqs are still not getting executed so the fallback is immediately triggered. I tried disabling the circuitBreaker (which I don't want to, that's why I'm using hystrix) to see if it did anything -- and it did. 80% of the requests passed through.

```
(hystrix/defcommand fetch-request
    {:hystrix/group-key "ct0"
     :hystrix/command-key "URLFetch"
     :hystrix/init-fn 
        (fn [_ ^com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$Setter setter]
            (.andCommandPropertiesDefaults
                setter
                ^com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommandProperties$Setter 
                (.withCircuitBreakerEnabled
                    (HystrixCommandProperties/Setter)
                    false)
            ;   ^com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommandProperties$Setter 
            ;   (.withExecutionTimeoutInMilliseconds
            ;       (HystrixCommandProperties/Setter)
            ;       1000))
            ; (.andCommandPropertiesDefaults
            ;   setter
            ;   (.withExecutionIsolationStrategy
            ;       (HystrixCommandProperties/Setter)
            ;        com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommandProperties$ExecutionIsolationStrategy/THREAD)
                ))
     :hystrix/fallback-fn 
        (fn fetch-req-fallback [url]
            {:status 419
             :headers {}
             :body "failed"})}
    [url]
    @(http/get url))
```

Update 2:

Removing the `thread` block fixes the problem. However, I do need to execute these requests across multiple thread so it doesn't necessarily solve my issue.

Comment: Why does the code dereference http/get? What http client library is it using?

Comment: http-kit client. The deference makes it a sync call

Comment: Check the hystrix configuration, e.g. https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/Configuration#CommandProperties. A hystrix resource is being consumed- circuit breaker size, threadpool size, etc- causing the fallback-fn to be called, which returns 419, which via the match gets printed as nil

Comment: I must say it is a very convincing name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it. I had to modify the threadpool properties.

```
(hystrix/defcommand fetch-request
  {:hystrix/group-key "ct0"
   :hystrix/command-key "URLFetch"
   :hystrix/thread-pool-key "URLThread"
   :hystrix/init-fn
   (fn [_ ^com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$Setter setter]
     (.andThreadPoolPropertiesDefaults
      setter
      (doto (HystrixThreadPoolProperties/Setter)
        (.withMaxQueueSize 10)
        (.withQueueSizeRejectionThreshold 10)))

     (.andCommandPropertiesDefaults
      setter
      (doto (HystrixCommandProperties/Setter)
        (.withExecutionIsolationStrategy
         com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommandProperties$ExecutionIsolationStrategy/THREAD)
        (.withExecutionTimeoutInMilliseconds
         1500))))
   :hystrix/fallback-fn
   (fn fetch-req-fallback [url]
     {:status 419
      :headers {}
      :body "failed"})}
  [url]
  @(http/get url))
```